# Under group action, can we define the stabilizer for a set of points?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let a group $G$ act on a space $S$. If a point $p$ in the space remains invariant under the action of a subgroup of $G$, we call the subgroup the stabilizer of $p$.

$\text{Stab}(p) = \{g: g \in G, \, p\in S, \, g.p = p\}$

Can the notion of stabilizer be extended to a set of points (say $P$) in the space rather than a single point? i.e. can we define a subgroup in the following way?

$\{g: g \in G, \, P\subset S, \, g.p_i = p_j \, \forall \, p_i, p_j \in P\}$

If so, what is such a group called?

Comment: The second sentence in your post is inaccurate, and your definition of ${\rm Stab}(p)$ is wrong, because the condition $p \in S$ belongs outside of the brackets $\{\}$, not inside. Similarly, $P \subset S$ should be outside of the brackets in your definition of ${\rm Stab}(P)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a subset $S'$ of $S$, define $Stab_1(S') = \bigcap_{p\in S'} Stab(p)$ which is the point-wise stabilizer of $S'$. This is a subgroup of $G$ since the intersection of subgroups is itself a subgroup.

Another set to consider is $Stab_2(S') = \{g\in G\mid g\cdot S'\subseteq S'\}$ which stabilizes the subset $S'$. Can you check whether this set is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am not sure which case you have mentioned is what I was thinking. Let me give an example of what I was thinking. Consider the action of the symmetry group of the cube ($S_4$) on the 3D space. Consider a plane of symmetry of the cube that is parallel to one of its faces. It seems to me that this plane maps to itself under $D_8$ (a subgroup of $S_4$). Isn't it correct?

Comment: Setwise and pointwise stabilizers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2999966/setwise-stabilizer-and-relationship-with-pointwise-stabilizer